# IOS - Old version of app being installed from the app store

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios7

I released an update to my app 2 days ago.  Since then I have heard from users that they are getting the old version of the app.

The really odd part is that the user is seeing the new app description and screenshots in the app store.

I have figured out how to reliably reproduce the issue.  Is this something that I can fix myself?  I've contacted Apple and searched the web but have found nothing so far.

**To get the old version:**

1. Go to appstore.  Find SocialPar.
2. Click to install the app.
3. While it is downloading, go back the iPhone main screen (spingboard).  You will see the app installing.
4. You now have the old version of the app

**To get the new version:**

1. Go to appstore.  Find SocialPar.
2. Click to install the app.
3. Wait in the appstore for the install to complete,
4. Click open
5. It will prompt for passwords to itunes account
6. It will install **again**
7. Click open **again**
8. You now have the proper version of the app.

I am wasting a lot of money promoting my app right now and its killing me that my marketing efforts are driving people to install an old version of my app.

Can anyone reproduce this with their apps?

Comment: It may take up to a few hours for AppStore to display a newly approved app.

Comment: Wait a day. It should adjust. Otherwise email apple support. Most likely won't take more than a few hours

Comment: I have a similar problem with an app I updated a couple of weeks ago. The app downloads the old version the first time then if you go back into the app store the install button has changed to an update button. If you click this you'll then get the latest version. Did you find a resolution?

Comment: The problem eventually went away but I did contact Apple so I can't be sure if they changed something or it naturally worked itself out.  My guess is that it took about a week.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably related to iCloud as I was having a very similar problem. If you have previously downloaded your app on any device then when you download it on a new device, it will download the same version as you previously downloaded. You then get the option to update to the latest version.

Confused me to start with!

Comment: This confuses me too! Apple should have some kind of alert saying it will download previous version due to iCloud sync. I downloaded the app in previous version and the cloud button changed to `UPDATE` after download. I have to tap download again to get the latest version.

Answer (score 9):

Apple is now allowing users to [download older versions of your app](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5919).

You can prevent this by going to iTunes connect and visiting your app's "Rights and Pricing" section. At the bottom there's a "Manage iCloud download settings for this app" link where you can exclude older version from being available.

Comment: Fyi, we have been running into this problem and this solution does not work for us.