# IOS - Old app version being installed from the app store

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, itunes

I released an update of my app 2 weeks ago on itunes. User is seeing the new app description and screenshots in the app store but downloads previous version and giving UPDATE option rather than OPEN option on itunes page.When I click on UPDATE button then again app downloads updated version.This happens only for iPhone devices with **iOS 6** installed in it.For device with iOS 7, app works fine with updated version installed from itunes.

Any one know why this happens?

similar question-[IOS - Old version of app being installed from the app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413417/ios-old-version-of-app-being-installed-from-the-app-store)

Comment: What is the deployment target for your new build on itunes?

Comment: How has it not updated?

Answer (score 1):

If the update is targeting 7.0 and you haven't updated the rights & pricing section of the app to disable download of old versions of an app from iCloud I believe that this behavior has been known to happen.